# Saved date does not show up in the form

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel livewire and I've created a page that you can select a date for when you want the post
to publish. When I create a new post and save the date then it saves fine in the database, but if I try
to edit the post and change the date the date that I saved in the database isn't showing in the form.

Here is my code.
My EditPost.php

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Livewire;

    use App\Models\Post;
    use Livewire\Component;

    class EditPost extends Component
    {
        public $name;
        public $publishDate;

        public Post $post;

        public function mount(Post $post)
        {
            $this->name = $post->name;
            $this->publishDate = $post->publish_date;
        }
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.edit-post');
        }
    }
```

and this is my edit.blade.php

```
    <div>
        <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
            <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
                <div class="md:col-span-1">
                    <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
                        <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Edit Post</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
                    <div class="form">
                        <div class="shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
                            <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
                                <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                                        <label for="name" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-700">Name</label>
                                        <input id="name" wire:model="name" class="@error('name') border border-red-500 @enderror mt-1 form-input block w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">

                                        @error('name')
                                            <small>
                                                <div class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</div>
                                            </small>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                                        <label for="publish_date" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-700">Publish Date</label>
                                        <input id="publish_date" wire:model="publishDate" type="date" class="mt-1 form-input block w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                                <button wire:click="editPost" class="py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue active:bg-indigo-600 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                                    Save
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is your date format??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - it's dateTime

Comment: your input type is date. you are putting a dateTime value in it. how's that gonna show up??

Comment: I changed my input type to datetime-local and created a new post, but when I go to edit my post it still doesn't show up